# Creating External Object Heroku Connect

Tags: externalobjects, heroku-connect

***Tldr; I am wondering if I create an External Object in Salesforce using my External Data Source (Heroku Connect to Heroku Postgres) if the object should be created automatically in Postgres?***

I have a Heroku App, with the requisite resources (Heroku Postgres, Heroku Connect), etc. [image: Heroku Resources]

I have successfully connected to my database as an External Data Source (OData 4.0), and synced a table that I first created using pgAdmin, then after adding a primary key, I am able to make the Object available to Salesforce in the `External Objects` tab of Heroku Connect resource:

[image: Heroku Connect Data Sources]

However when I create a new External Object in Salesforce, and click "Validate" under the data-source I get an exception.

[image: Next External Object]

[image: Validate New External Object]

[image: Error when Validating]

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-connect-mappings

Comment: @identigral, my external object does not appear to be available for mapping are you implying this is what I should be doing?

Comment: That is Heroku Connect implementation, yes. You might be in Salesforce Connect land. Similar but not the same - check https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce_heroku_integration